# Node: how to pass the image file received and pass it to Flutter using Gateway Node

Tags: node.js

I have an image GET request from **Flutter -> Gateway NodeJS -> Image NodeJS**. I have checked that getting an image from 'Image NodeJS' works fine.

This is the code of the gateway nodejs.

```
const imageFromNode = await axios.get(
        `${url}`,
        req.body,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      res.sendFile(imageFromNode);
```

I am sending file with `sendFile` from `Image NodeJS`. Moreover, on Flutter, I am using `cache_network_image` package.

How can I send the received image jpg file and pass it to Flutter's `cache_network_image` widget without saving on `Gateway Nodejs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname + `/../${q}.jpg`)
    );
```

Get the file like this and send it over to the Gateway Nodejs.

```
const fromGateway = await axios.get(
    `${url}/?q=${q}`,
    req.body,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  res.send(fromGateway.data);
```

And then return the file like this to Flutter worked. You will be able to use it as jpg.